# Call mvn war:war automatically on mvn package but output JAR as well

Tags: maven, jar, war

I'm new to maven and I am using the maven war plugin to generate a WAR file for my project.

```
mvn war:war
```

But I would like this to be done automatically when I run

```
mvn package
```

How do I modify pom.xml to do this?

EDIT:

To clarify, I still want a JAR file *as well* as the WAR file. I am currently building a JAR with dependencies using

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

and

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.fb.Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: add `<packaging>war</packaging>` to your pom.xml and also add the war plugin

Comment: Hi, sorry for being unclear. My project currently outputs a JAR with included dependencies but I would like it to output a WAR _as well_. I know this is a bad idea in general, but the JAR is simply a small HTTP server that enables me to send people a prototype without having to ask them to install Tomcat or similar first. I'll edit the question to become more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put "war" packaging at the beginning of your pom.xml.
Then add the following to your build section.

```
<build>
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>make-a-jar</id>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <goals>
     <goal>jar</goal>
    </goals>
   </execution>
  </executions>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```